# HTML DOM: Can't edit element value programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to automate few tasks on some websites, including Google Finance. But, when I try to edit the input value in Google Finance Search Input, it simply doesn't work. Is there anyone who can help me out with this?

I have already tried the following code in console:

```js
element = document.querySelector("input\[class='yNVtPc ZAGvjd Ny5lGc'\]")
element.value = "RELIANCE"
element2 = document.querySelector("input[class='Ax4B8 ZAGvjd']")
element2.value = "RELIANCE"
```

I even tried removing disabled attribute and changing default value, still no luck.

Furthermore, I tried the following function as well:

```js
const sendKeys = async (el, str) => {
    let val = "";
    const keys = str.split("");
    for (const key of keys) {
      console.log(key);
      val += key;
      el.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key })
      );
      
      el.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key })
      );
      
      el.value = val;
      
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
      
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
      
      el.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keyup", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key })
      );
      
    }
    return true;
  };
```

But, even this one also doesn't work.
Is there any solution or workaround so as I can type the text to that input field programmatically?

Comment: Check your keys variable if value is coming properly or not. Sometimes it take values from other source and edit field will be not editable. So, first check keys and str values.

Comment: I recommend you skip that step, since in fact this is implemented on purpose to avoid automation, what you can try is to make the XHR requests that Google makes yourself

Comment: In fact, this input only serves to show what has been written and is not stored in "value"

Comment: Just set the value character by character, you can't make or emulate useractions.

Comment: @RafaelDorado actually I have built a chrome extension that can automate web-flow for any assigned task using Gen AI, but it can't work on few websites including Google Finance for the said reason. That's why I specifically need to automate the typing on that particular website than sending XHR or fetch request. Here's the public demo of the product: [Web Auto](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7145807898604953600/) Thank you btw:)

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Answer (score 1):

Special thanks to Meijing Xue for sharing with me the that Google Finance is having multiple input tags, and with querySelectorAll, element value can be set.

After digging in, I discovered that in actual there are only two input elements with two duplicate elements, one each.

**Solution:**

```js
function performPressKeyAction(element) {
  // Find the element using the provided selector
  if (element) {
    // If the element is found, create a KeyboardEvent for pressing Enter
    const enterEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      key: "Enter",
      code: "Enter",
      keyCode: 13,
      which: 13,
      bubbles: true
    });

    // Dispatch the created KeyboardEvent on the element
    element.dispatchEvent(enterEvent);
    console.log("1");
  } else {
    // Log an error if the element is not found
    console.error("Element not found for selector:", element);
  }
}
async function sleep(milliseconds) {
    return await new Promise((r, _) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            r();
        }, milliseconds);
    });
}

const sendKeys = async (el, str) => {
    let val = "";
    const keys = str.split("");
    for (const key of keys) {
      console.log(key);
      val += key;
      el.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key })
      );
      await sleep(200);
      el.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key })
      );
      await sleep(200);
      el.value = val;
      await sleep(200);
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
      await sleep(200);
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
      await sleep(200);
      el.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keyup", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key })
      );
      await sleep(200);
    }
    return true;
  };

var element = document.querySelectorAll("input[class='Ax4B8 ZAGvjd']");

// then try to enter value and hit click for element of that particular class [one of them is duplicate element for both kinda elements]

element.forEach(e => {
  sendKeys(e, "RELIANCE")
});

// Run this only after the keys have been typed
element.forEach(e => {
    performPressKeyAction(e)
});
```

Thanks again, Meijing bro :)

Comment: Why not: 
`const sendKeys = async (el, str) => {
      el.value = str;
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
      return true;
    };`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried just now, there are 4 Input tag in https://www.google.com/finance/ page, when i use single querySelector and set value, nothing changed.
But when i change to querySelectorAll, it works

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input");
[...elements].map(i => i.value = 'RELIANCE');
```

But it still makes me weird, single querySelector works in normal pages, maybe google changed getters and setters or something stuff

Comment: yes, I just noticed that too. But, still I can't press Enter like on other websites. Actually, what I noticed is Google is having two duplicate inputs, making it total 4 input field. For ex.:
```javascript

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[class='yNVtPc ZAGvjd Ny5lGc']");
[...elements].map(i => i.value = 'RELIANCE'); 

``` 
returns 2 input elements. Is there anyway I can click Enter after typing text here, like on other websites?

Comment: btw, thanks a ton:) unfortunately i can't upvote your answer, as I am a new Contributor and needs at-least 15 reps to upvote answers.

Comment: thanks a lot brother, I found out the way to make it work. Sharing it in as an answer, as there's a word limit in comments.

Comment: You're welcome and I'm glad I could assist. However, I regret to inform you that the solution didn't work as expected on my end. It redirected to the default page, and setting the value wasn't successful. I observed that only the last input  document.querySelector(".VOEIyf .Ax4B8") is binding to EventListeners. These EventListeners, which you can locate near the DOM styles and computed sections, seem to be linked to a call function. Unfortunately, I'm unable to upload an image here for better clarification. After consulting ChatGPT, it mentioned that the code involves one-time events and so on

Comment: bro, I actually thought element.value would work, as the code was working on my end. I noticed that I am having sendKeys function to achieve the same. Try the updated code, and it will work like charm. Also, call this line after execution of lines above it:
```element.forEach(e => {
    performPressKeyAction(e)
});```

Comment: though personally, I donno why e.value doesn't work but sendKeys function works.